# ale_floating_preview not working

Tags: plugin-ale

ale does not popup anything automatically.
Neovim 0.5.0, windows 10.
I wonder whether I configured ale correctly, since nothing related shown in ALEInfo.
in init.vim, `mouse=a`

```
let g:ale_open_list = 0
"let g:ale_hover_cursor = 1 " default=1, to show info in echo line
let g:ale_floating_preview = 1
let g:ale_hover_to_floating_preview = 1
"let g:ale_set_balloons = 1
let g:ale_hover_to_preview = 0

Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
```

I tried different combinations of these switches, but results were same.
Thank you in advance.

1. open a go file
2. place the cursor at a variable
3. place the mouse at another
4. info of variable at cursor shown in echo line. but info of variable at mouse does not show anywhere
5. :ALEHover shows popup=?floating window at cursor

#### :ALEInfo

```
 Current Filetype: go
Available Linters: ['bingo', 'gobuild', 'gofmt', 'golangci-lint', 'golint', 'gometalinter', 'gopls', 'gosimple', 'gotype', 'govet', 'golangserver', 'revive', 'staticcheck']
   Linter Aliases:
'gobuild' -> ['go build']
'govet' -> ['go vet']
  Enabled Linters: ['gopls']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'gofmt' - Fix Go files with go fmt.
  'goimports' - Fix Go files imports with goimports.
  'golines' - Fix Go file long lines with golines
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_go_go_executable = 'go'
let g:ale_go_golangci_lint_executable = 'golangci-lint'
let g:ale_go_golangci_lint_options = '--enable-all'
let g:ale_go_golangci_lint_package = 0
let g:ale_go_gopls_executable = 'gopls'
let g:ale_go_gopls_init_options = {}
let g:ale_go_gopls_options = '--mode stdio'
let g:ale_go_gopls_use_global = 0
let g:ale_go_langserver_executable = 'go-langserver'
let g:ale_go_langserver_options = ''
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'go': ['gopls']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_root = {}
let g:ale_set_balloons = 1
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:

(executable check - success) gopls
(started) 'cmd /s/c "gopls --mode stdio"'
```

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, sorry I got the info in a vim file and corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

For errors, `g:ale_cursor_detail` determines whether the popup shows up automatically or not.

For general `:ALEHover` information, you have to write your own autocommand:

```
augroup ale_hover_cursor
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorHold * ALEHover
augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It pops automatically under cursor.

Comment: I wonder why it does not pop under mouse when g:ale_set_balloons=1 or anything

Comment: @A117 balloons in the terminal are tricky. Ive never been able to get ale to work with them. (But if you like the popup support in newer vims, that was me :).)

Comment: PS Say “thanks” with an upvote, or “this solved my problem” with an accept :)